# JVM Crashes because of NLNVP.DLL (Lotus Notes)

Tags: jvm, lotus

I'm trying to Download attachments from Lotus notes, but JVM Crashes with this error:

EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005)

## Problematic frame:

## C  [NLNVP.DLL]

Crash is cause by this method from Domino library:
extractFile(path);

once it hits this line, JVM goes down.

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: NLNVP.DLL is related to Symantec anti-virus, so you need to check with them or your IT department.

Comment: Questions like this are better asked on [Superuser](http://superuser.com/). SO is for programming questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Remove line NLNVP.DLL from notes.ini and try to execute it will not crash the JVM
2. you (developer) and end user have same symantic version then JVM will not crash.